# Continuous audio recording and analysis

Tags: android, audio-recording, mediarecorder

I would like to write an app the records audio continuously and analyze it in real time. I already know how to record file once and play it back, but I don't know how to make it continuous. I suppose there is some sort of circular buffer file in Java API, but I am quite new to Java and I didn't get my head around the APIs yet. Also can I keep this file entirely in memory, not to introduce overhead of writing to external storage? Any ideas?